# How to know which version of Xamarin.Android sdk is referred for Xamarin Android project in Azure Hosted VS2017 Agent?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have Xamarin Android project using Azure Hosted VS2017 to build its packages. I have updated the Xamarin packages and tried to generate a build from the pipeline. It's able to build it successfully but when I ran the app, Fatal exception is thrown.

```
10-02 12:40:53.943 7921-7921/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.telstra.lot, PID: 7921
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
    at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.DirectoryExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00000] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.DirectoryExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00000] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.Exists (System.String path) [0x0001e] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0 
  at FFImageLoading.Cache.SimpleDiskCache..ctor (System.String cachePath, FFImageLoading.Config.Configuration configuration) [0x00069] in <e4a68679a2a44c4694e04140bb609f9a>:0 
  at FFImageLoading.ImageService.CreatePlatformDiskCacheInstance (FFImageLoading.Config.Configuration configuration) [0x00075] in <e4a68679a2a44c4694e04140bb609f9a>:0 
  at FFImageLoading.ImageServiceBase`1[TImageContainer].InitializeIfNeeded (FFImageLoading.Config.Configuration userDefinedConfig) [0x00137] in <a159011f32534c8eb0455a9cf0bad5a7>:0 
  at FFImageLoading.ImageServiceBase`1[TImageContainer].Initialize () [0x00021] in <a159011f32534c8eb0455a9cf0bad5a7>:0
```

Its working fine with the build generated from VS for mac which has the Xamarin.Android version 9.4x. So I'm wondering the hosted VS2017 pointing an old version of Xamairn.Android sdk.

I can find a version in the build logs from the pipeline

> _ResolveXamarinAndroidTools:
>
> Looking for Android NDK...
>
> Found Xamarin.Android 9.1.7.0
>
> Found Xamarin.Android 9.1.7.0

Answer (score 0):

You have [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops) links to all the included software on the agents.

To Azure Hosted VS2017 this is the [page](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md) and you can see there these versions:

**Android SDK Platforms**

10 (API 29):
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-29

9 (API 28):
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-28

8.1.0 (API 27):
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-27

8.0.0 (API 26):
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-26

7.1.1 (API 25):
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-25

7.0 (API 24):
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-24

6.0 (API 23):
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-23

5.1.1 (API 22):
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-22

5.0.1 (API 21):
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-21

4.4.2 (API 19):
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-19